# Django form error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: legal_useragreedtolegal.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Whenever, I call form.save() I get "**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: legal_useragreedtolegal.user_id**"

I think this might be because I have a oneToOneField and Django is trying to save to UserAgreedToLegal and User Model but the User model already has that ID, so the unique constraint fails, but not sure.

I am wondering how I can fix this issue. I listed my model, form, and view code below

models.py

```py
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone as django_timezone


class UserAgreedToLegal(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agreed_first_terms_of_service = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, null=False)
    date_agreed = models.DateField(null=True, default=django_timezone.now)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms

from legal.models import UserAgreedToLegal


class TermsOfServiceAgreementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAgreedToLegal
        fields = [
            'agreed_first_terms_of_service'
        ]
```

views.py

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TermsOfServiceAgreementForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.clean()
            terms_of_service_agreement = form.save(commit=False)
            terms_of_service_agreement.user = request.user

            terms_of_service_agreement.save()
```

The result is

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: legal_useragreedtolegal.user_id
```

Comment: A `OneToOneField` means there can not be two or more `UserAgreedToLegal`s for the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was failing was because there was a OneToOne relationship with the django user model, and when I called form.save() it was trying to save a new row (insert a new user) into both User and my model and then it would see that this user_id already exists in my model and it would tell me that it cannot be done because then it would violate a rule that I placed of having only a one to one relationship because if it did save each one user would have many records. That would create a one to many instead of a one to one.

Instead, what I needed to do was to tell django that I don't want to insert a new record in my model, or to update it if that record already exists and if not create it while maintaining its relationship with the User model.

I had to pass in an instance for Django Forms to know that I already have this model and I don't want to update this instance.

here is the code that worked for me

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    my_user = UserAgreedToLegal.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)[0]
    form = TermsOfServiceAgreementForm(request.POST, instance=my_user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.clean()
        terms = form.save(commit=False)
        terms.user = request.user
        terms.save()
```

Comment: this is inside of the view when validating the request and saving the form

Answer (score 1):

> I think this might be because I have a `OneToOneField` and Django is trying to save to UserAgreedToLegal and User Model but the User model already has that ID, so the unique constraint fails, but not sure.

You are correct, a `OneToOneField` is in essence a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`. It thus makes no sense to visit this view a second time.

You can check if the person already has agreed to the legal terms, and if that is the case redirect to a page, for example a view that renders a page to explain that the user already agreed, so something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    if UserAgreedToLegal.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # …
    # …
```

where the *`name-of-some-view`* should point to a view that will render that page.

Comment: I am not revisiting this view. It is the first time the user is visiting this view

Comment: @AugustusCaesar: well the `UserAgreedToLegal` exists for that user, not per se in that view, but then another view, or signal created the `UserAgreedToLegal` object.